# Can we use Bootstrap to estimate MSE?

Tags: inference, bootstrap, causality, mse, bart

The classic problem in causality is that we do not observe the ground truth--the actual treatment effect. Let's say I have several methods in my toolkit (CART, causal tree, causal forest, BART etc.) and I want to evaluate their performance in accurately estimating treatment effects. The classic approach would be to assume a data generating process where we pre-specify the treatment effects and then run simulations. The problem with simulations is that it relies on accurate description of the DGP.

I am wondering if instead it is possible to use bootstrap method to estimate MSE in each method. We know MSE is the sum of bias squared plus variance. In principle, we can use resampling to calculate both the terms in each method. With this, we will have MSE associated with each method and by comparing bootstrapped MSE for each method, we can evaluate model performance. What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually, I think I found an answer. There is a history of using jackknife/bootstrap to estimate bias and variance of estimators (MSE can be decomposed into a bias and a variance part) http://people.bu.edu/aimcinto/jackknife.pdf